# Access 2007 Show Full Screen

Tags: ms-access-2007

Can anyone tell me how I can show the full screen on a Form in Access 2007 so that there are no Toolbars etc open, so no one can tamper with anything ?

Cheers,
Nick C

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for doing this. One of the slickest I've seen is listed below. Unfortunately, I don't remember where I got this code from, so I can't give credit where it's due.

Post the code below into a new module in your database.

```
Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Function DoAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long)
' This function can minimize Access behind the scenes.

'Usage Examples
'Maximize window:
'       ?DoAccessWindow(SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
'Minimize window:
'       ?DoAccessWindow(SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
'Hide window:
'       ?DoAccessWindow(SW_HIDE)
'Normal window:
'       ?DoAccessWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)
'
Dim loX  As Long
Dim loform As Form
    On Error Resume Next
    Set loform = Screen.ActiveForm
    If Err <> 0 Then 'no Activeform
      If nCmdShow = SW_HIDE Then
        MsgBox "Cannot hide Access unless a form is on screen"
      Else
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
        Err.Clear
      End If
    Else
        If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loform.Modal = True Then
            MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " & (loform.Caption + " ") & "form on screen"
        ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loform.PopUp <> True Then
            MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " & (loform.Caption + " ") & "form on screen"
        Else
            loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
        End If
    End If
    DoAccessWindow = (loX <> 0)
End Function
```

Now you can use the DoAccessWindow() function to mess with the Access window. You may want to play around with the hide option, as it totally hides the Access interface. A word of warning, any form you want to display must be Popup and Modal in order to be visible.

So for instance, on the Form_Open event, you could use the code DoAccessWindow(0) to hide Access's interface, then on the Form_Close event, you would use DoAccessWindow(1) to show the interface again.